# Toplevel window with hover on button and the toplevel window itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm nooby for Python and for practice, I trying to create an Audio player with Tkinter
Now I am trying to create a Toplevel window to change the volume, as in many players or browsers
The basic idea and complexity lies in the fact that the window should appear when you hover the cursor on the “button” and disappear when the cursor leaves the button and the dialog box itself (example: like on Youtube)
I know, there is a Bind event like Motion or Enter/Leave. But how to make sure that the space of the Toplevel widget is taken into account, and not just the button?

Comment: What if you bind "<Enter>" to `Toplevel.deiconify()`  and bind "<Leave>" to `Toplevel.iconify()` also bind the same for the Toplevel window so when the cursor is on the window it doesn't close yet till you're not hovering either on the button or the window itself. You can play with it like binding '<Enter>' to `Button` and '<Leave>' to `Toplevel` window should do the trick as well.

Comment: You mean...create that Toplevel window and let it exist always?
Let him only fold and unfold it with bind?

Answer (score 0):

Getting a volume hover over a window can be done by multiple ways you can hover a `Frame` as well instead of using `Toplevel` window but idea of using `Toplevel()` gives you more options to customise and make it look nicer like I did.

- I made a function which can be assigned to any button just by `Button.bind("<Enter>", change_volume)` independently.
- In the function, a Toplevel window will create on *""* and `destroy()` on "" accordingly.
- I used [`wm_overrideredirect(True)`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.overrideredirect-method) to remove the decorations from the `Toplevel` window such as titlebar borders around the edges of the window.
- I also used a little bit of *-alpha* attribute to give some transparency to the window by [`attributes('-alpha', 0.6)`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.attributes-method).
- You can also use the [ttk themed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html) `Scale` it has a round knob and looks better than default one and also ttk is pre-installed just like tkinter. But it returns a *float* value where as normal `Scale` returns *integer*.

***Restuls:***

_________<sub>(Defualt)</sub>_________ .  ________<sub>(ttk themed)</sub>________

[image: HoverVolume]..[image]

***Code sample:***

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk  # for round knob scale widget

root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'lightyellow'
root.geometry('200x200+100+100')
volvar = IntVar(value=5)

def change_volume(evt=None):
    global vol_wid
    wid = evt.widget  # Get the widget the instance
    # Try / except to avoid errors like AttributeError.. 
    try: 
        # Returns if a window alrealy present
        if vol_wid.winfo_exists(): return 
    except: pass
    vol_wid = Toplevel(root)
    vol_wid.wm_overrideredirect(True)  # Removes the titlrbar and borders
    vol_wid.update()   # Don't need if not on macos
    vol_wid.lift()
    vol_wid.attributes('-alpha', 0.6) # Makes the window transparent
    vol_wid.attributes('-topmost', 1) # Be on top of every window
    scale = Scale(vol_wid, from_=0, to=10, variable=volvar, orient='horizontal', 
               bg='black', fg='white')    # NORMAL DEFAULT SCALE
    # scale = ttk.Scale(vol_wid, from_=0, to=10, variable=volvar, 
    #           orient='horizontal')    # ROUND KNOB SCALE
    scale.pack()
    # Set the window just above the button 
    width = int((scale.winfo_reqwidth() - wid.winfo_width()) / 2)
    vol_wid.geometry('+%s+%s' %(wid.winfo_rootx()-width, 
            wid.winfo_rooty()-scale.winfo_reqheight()))
    vol_wid.focus()  # Gives focus
    vol_wid.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: vol_wid.destroy()) # Bind to destroy window

Label(root, textvariable=volvar, font=('',16)).pack(pady=25)
B = Button(root, text='Volume',bg='lightpink', padx=10)
B.pack(pady=25)
B.bind("<Enter>", change_volume)
mainloop()
```